# Unable to pass unique data during segue

Tags: ios, objective-c, segue

I am having trouble getting the unique data from the selected table cell. Every cell I click seems to pass the same data. Any advise on what I did wrong here?

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MallToVendor"]) {
        MingieAdvertisementIndividualViewController *destViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
        destViewController.mallName = [[advertisements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name];
    }
}
```

Comment: You can pass unique data as `sender` where you call `- (void)performSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender`

Comment: Can you try NSLog the `[[advertisements objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] name]` bit and see if they actually print different datas each row?

Comment: try using NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender] where sender is the cell

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `indexPathForSelectedRow`, save the selected `indexpath.row` in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method in an *integer variable* and use it in `prepareForSegue`.

If you use `indexPathForSelectedRow` it will always return `indexpath` of the first row.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Define this property in your @implementation file

```
@property(nonatomic) int indexOfSelectedRow;
```

In your `didSelectROwAtIndexPath`method  do this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    self.indexOfSelectedRow=indexPath.row;


}
```

And in your `prepareForSegue` method, do this-

```
 - (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"MallToVendor"]) 
  {
    MingieAdvertisementIndividualViewController *destViewController=segue.destinationViewController;
    destViewController.mallName = [[advertisements objectAtIndex:self.indexOfSelectedRow] name];
  }
}
```